# why function showing not defined in enthought canopy?

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

I am a new user in Enthought Canopy Python.

** At first I tried to run the code, it gave error message e.g.

> MatrixCreate is not defined.

** Then I tried importing the file by typing command: e.g.

> import file.py ; it gave error "no module named file.py"

** Then I tried:

> import MatrixCreate(1, 50);

gave me error message `invalid syntax` with arrow directing before braces.

** Then I tried importing the function from matplot: e.g.

```
from matplotlib import matrixcreate;
```

it gave error message

> cannot import matrixcreate

** further I tried:

```
matrixcreate.show();
```

gave me error

> name 'matixcreate' is not defined

Please guide how I can run my code.

Comment: 1) What is `MatrixCreate`? 2) Where does `MatrixCreate` come from? -- We do not have a crystal ball.

Comment: I am trying to run this command: print MatrixCreate(1, 50)

Comment: What makes you think that matrixcreate is a submodule of matplotlib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MatrixCreate` does not appear to be a part of any module that you could import. Most probably you are using some incomplete code that is missing a function called `MatrixCreate`. However, to create an empty matrix of the size [1, 50] use:

```
import numpy
matrix = numpy.zeros(shape=(1,50))
print matrix
```

you can further make a function that creates a matrix for you:

```
import numpy
def MatrixCreate(a,b):
   matrix = numpy.zeros(shape=(a,b))
   return matrix
print MatrixCreate(1,50)
```